# Discord bot message "application not responding"

Tags: python, discord, bots, pycord

I have a problem in my code.

this is my admin code :

```
import discord

class Admin(discord.Cog):
    
    def __init__(self, bot):
        self.bot = bot
        self._last_member = None

    @discord.command(name='clear', description='Permet de purger les messages du chat textuel.')
    async def clear(self, ctx:discord.ApplicationContext, amount):
        await ctx.channel.purge(limit=int(amount))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import main
```

this is my main code :

```
# Import discord libs
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

# Import addon libs
import random
import asyncio

# Import extra libs
from libs import settings

# Import Cogs
import admin

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix=" ", help_command=None, intents=discord.Intents.default())

client.add_cog(admin.Admin(client))

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print(f"logged in as {client.user}")
    print("Bot is ready!")
    await client.change_presence(status=discord.Status.online)

async def changepresence():
    await client.wait_until_ready()
    statuses = settings.BotStatus
    while not client.is_closed():
        status =  random.choice(statuses)
        await client.change_presence(activity=discord.Game(name=status))
        await asyncio.sleep(10)

client.loop.create_task(changepresence())
client.run(settings.TOKEN)
```

this is my console in Visual studio code :

[image]

when i use my command /clear amount: he result this error :
but the command /clear amount: working perfectly :D

[image]

Can you help me to fix this please :D ?

Comment: Interactions need to respond in 3 seconds. If they don't you will get this error. Whatever library you are using that's not discord.py should have something in its documentation. You are also gonna get rate limited with that presence task.

Comment: @puncher : That's not discord.py  ??

Comment: @LightNox no. Idk which library you're using but e.g. `ApplicationContext` doesn't exist in discord.py. Maybe you use one of the forks pycord or nextcord?

Comment: @puncher That's discord.py, you can see from the import

Comment: I made a quick research and `ApplicationContext` can't be found in `discord.py` but in `pycord`.

Comment: oh, well then I was wrong. Didn't know they looked so similar

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. [Please don't post screenshots of text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/354577). They can't be searched or copied, or even consumed by users of adaptive technologies like screen readers. Instead, paste the code as text directly into your question. If you select it and click the `{}` button or Ctrl+K the code block will be indented by four spaces, which will cause it to be rendered as code.

Comment: I have edit my post.
Have you a solution to fix this issue with pycord ?

Comment: @puncher : Have you a solution for resolve this issue please :D ?

Comment: @LightNox I don't know pycord, I use discord.py sorry

Comment: @puncher : its nothing ^^ thanks :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to have the bot respond to the interaction: `interaction.response.send_message("message")`